# how to use socket.io in a swifui project?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, socket.io

I'm trying to create a chat in my swiftui app.

I've added all the packages.

I have a chatView that looks like this at the moment:

```
import SwiftUI
import SocketIO



struct chatView: View {
    @State private var socket: SocketIOClient!
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Welcome to my app!")
            Button(action: {
                socket.emit("message", ["Hello from SwiftUI!"])
            }) {
                Text("Send Message")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            
            
            
          socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:3000")!)
           socket.connect()
        }
    }
}

struct chatView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        chatView()
    }
}
```

but the Xcode is complaining with this error:

```
Extra argument 'socketURL' in call
Missing arguments for parameters 'manager', 'nsp' in call
```

and the errors are shown next to this part of my code:

```
socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:3000")!)
```

I'm not sure whats causing this! can someone please advice on this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `SocketIOClient` has an initializer that takes a `socketURL` argument. It is `SocketManager`'s initializer that takes a `socketURL` argument.

[The `SocketIOClient` class reference](https://nuclearace.github.io/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Classes/SocketIOClient.html) says

> Clients are created through a [`SocketManager`](https://nuclearace.github.io/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Classes/SocketManager.html), which owns the [`SocketEngineSpec`](https://nuclearace.github.io/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Protocols/SocketEngineSpec.html) that controls the connection to the server.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> // Create a socket for the /swift namespace
> let socket = manager.socket(forNamespace: "/swift")
>
> // Add some handlers and connect
> ```

The [project README](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/blob/master/README.md) gives this example:

> ```
> let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:8080")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
> let socket = manager.defaultSocket
> ```